# C incompatible types when assigning to type 'struct Node' from type 'struct Node *'

Tags: c, pointers, struct, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I've only wrote the functions, and when I compile it, it always come out these errors.
I know that the problem was in `queue->arr[queue->rear]=item`. But I already defined my `queue->arr` as `Node*` in `Queue`, why would the code still be wrong?

```
[Error] incompatible types when assigning to type 'struct Node' from type 'struct Node *'
[Error] incompatible type for argument 1 of 'insertValue'
[Note] expected 'struct Node *' but argument is of type 'struct Node'
```

```
struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* left;
    struct Node* right;
};

struct Queue{
    int rear;
    int front;
    int size;
    int capacity;
    struct Node* arr;
};

struct Node* newNode(int item){
    struct Node* node=(struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    node->left= NULL;
    node->right=NULL;
    node->data= item;
    return node;
}

struct Queue* creatQ()
{
    struct Queue* queue= (struct Queue*)malloc(sizeof(struct Queue*));
    queue->rear=0;
    queue->front=0;
    queue->size=0;
    queue->capacity= MAXQUEUE;
    queue->arr=(struct Node*)malloc(queue->capacity*sizeof(struct Node));;
    return queue;
}

void push(struct Queue* queue, struct Node* item)
{
    if(queue->rear==(MAXQUEUE-1)){
        printf("Queue full\n");
    }
    else{
        queue->rear= (queue->rear+1)%queue->capacity;
        queue->arr[queue->rear]=item;
        queue->size++;
    }
}

struct Node pop(struct Queue* queue)
{
    struct Node item;
    if (queue->size==0){
        printf("Empty queue\n");
    }
    else{
        item=queue->arr[queue->front];
        queue->front= (queue->front+1)%queue->capacity;     
        queue->size--;      
        return item;
    }
}

struct Node front(struct Queue* queue)
{
    struct Node item;
    if(queue->size!=0){
        item=queue->arr[queue->front];
        return item;
    }
}

struct Node* insertValue(struct Node* root, int value, struct Queue* queue)
{
    struct Node* node= newNode(value);
    struct Node item= front(queue);
    if (root==NULL){
        root=node;
    }
    else if(item.left==NULL){
        item.left=node;
    }
    else {
        item.right=node;
        pop(queue);
    }
    
    push(queue, node);
    return root;
}
```

Comment: did you know that `queue->arr[queue->rear]` is the same as `*(queue->arr + queue->rear)`?

Comment: Welcome on stackoverflow. Take the [tour] first so you learn how this site works.

Comment: "But I already defined my queue->arr as Node*" yes, exactly. This means that `queue->arr[x]` is of type `struct Node`, not `struct Node*`

Comment: You probably want `queue->arr[queue->rear] = *item;` instead of `queue->arr[queue->rear] = item;`

Comment: The second error is not caused by the code you show. It is caused by the function call to `insertValue` which you do not show.

Comment: @Jabberwocky  Yeah, I think that's where the problem was `queue->arr[queue->rear] = *item` thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There are many errors. For example in this declaration

```
struct Queue* queue= (struct Queue*)malloc(sizeof(struct Queue*));
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

there is used an incorrect argument of the call of malloc. You need to write

```
struct Queue* queue= (struct Queue*)malloc(sizeof(struct Queue));
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Or within the function `push` there is a wrong assignment

```
queue->arr[queue->rear]=item;
```

The variable `item` has the type `struct Node *`

```
void push(struct Queue* queue, struct Node* item)
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

while the element type of the array pointed to by the pointer `arr` is `struct Node`.

Or the function `front` returns nothing if the data member size is equal to 0.

```
struct Node front(struct Queue* queue)
{
    struct Node item;
    if(queue->size!=0){
        item=queue->arr[queue->front];
        return item;
    }
}
```

Or this error message

```
[Error] incompatible type for argument 1 of 'insertValue'
[Note] expected 'struct Node *' but argument is of type 'struct Node'
```

says that somewhere you are calling the function passing to it an object of the type `struct Node` while the corresponding parameter has the type `struct Node *`.

```
struct Node* insertValue(struct Node* root, int value, struct Queue* queue)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Before writing any new function compile your program with a previously defined function. Do not write a new code if you are not sure that the already written code is valid.

Pay attention to that if you implemented the queue as an array then there is no great sense to define the array elements as having the data members `left` and `right`.

```
struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* left;
    struct Node* right;
};
```

New elements are added to the current tail in the array and popped out from its head.

Comment: The reason that I use `struct Node* left`  `struct Node*right` and `queue` is because that the actual question of this problem is: build a binary tree in level order from a unknown size of input. For example [0,0,0,null,0,0] , where the first 0 is the root and the second 0 is the left child of the root, and so on. If I caught the null, in this case, it supposed to be the very left node in level 3. But since it is a null, I don't put any node on there.

Comment: Because the input is an unknown size, the only method I could think of is to use queue. Or do you have any better ideas? I'm new to these data structure concepts....